# Travis CI for Android: failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.2

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci

I have set up Travis CI for [my project](https://github.com/evercam/evercam-play-android) a while ago and it worked. But the Travis build started failing from yesterday (I didn't make any change in my code).

The error was:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':evercamPlay:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 137
```

After searching around I see some discussions here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3695. So I added these code following the instructions:

```
global:
  - MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2
```

and

```
sudo: required
```

Then the error is gone but got a new one instead:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':evercamPlay'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.2
```

Here is my latest [travis.yml](https://github.com/evercam/evercam-play-android/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Any idea how to fix this and make the build pass again?

The strange thing is I didn't make any code changes but the build starts to fail. Is there anything new around Travis CI that I am not aware of?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Get a look here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5036 Try to use 23.0.1

Comment: Tried to build it again today and everything passed, there are something funny going on with Travis..